# GNU Makefile Copy using lists

Tags: makefile

I am VERY new to makefiles. I have discovered a flaw in a make file that causes files in a list to be copied from a single source file instead of each file in the list.

First, there is a sub model variable `SUB_MODEL_LIST` that contains `0 1 2 3` separated by white space.

Here is the segment that does the copy:

```
$(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW) : $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)
    @echo copying from $< to $@
    $(call COPY, $(firstword $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)), $@)
```

`TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW` contains new file names separated by white space and is composed of something like this:

```
file001.200 file001.201 file001.202 file001.203
```

and `TARGET_BIN_LIST` contains the existing file names and is composed of something like this:

```
file001c.200 file001c.201 file001c.202 file001c.203
```

The last digit in the file extension is the model number.
As I read this, the makefile runs:

```
@echo copying from $< to $@
$(call COPY, $(firstword $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)), $@)
```

four times, however, it always use the first file name in the `TARGET_BIN_LIST` due to the `firstword` function. This results in `file001.200, file001.201, file001.202, file001.203` being created, but they are all copies of `file001c.200` when they should be copies of their respective files in the list. Each file relates to a sub model version of the code.

My thought to solve this was to use the `word` function. Something like this:

```
$(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW) : $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)
    @echo copying from $< to $@
    $(call COPY, $(word $(sub), $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)), $@)
```

where `sub` is an element of SUB_MODEL_LIST, but I am not sure how that will work. Does the above roll out into 4 separate calls, or can it be looked at as a loop that can have an increment value for `sub`??

I also thought about using a foreach loop:

```
$(foreach sub,$(SUB_MODEL_LIST),$(call COPY, $(word $(sub), $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)), $(word $(sub), $(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW)))
```

But I get the error:

```
*** first argument to `word' function must be greater than 0.  Stop.
```

Ok, so I tried:

```
$(foreach sub,$(SUB_MODEL_LIST),$(call COPY, $(word $(sub)+1, $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)), $(word $(sub)+1, $(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW)))
```

But then I got the error:

```
*** non-numeric first argument to `word' function.  Stop.
```

Now I'm stuck. I would like to keep the existing implementation in tact at much as possible, but can adopt a loop method if needed.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thank you to MadScientist for your help in clarifying how this works.

This implementation worked for me:

```
 $(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW) : $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)
    @echo copying from $(filter %$(suffix $@), $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)) to $@
    $(call COPY, $(filter %$(suffix $@), $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)), $@)
```

Comment: This is an extremely strange rule, as I pointed out above.  What this rule says is that any time _ANY_ file in `TARGET_BIN_LIST` changes, _ALL_ targets in `TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW` are updated... even though "updating" is just copying each file separately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to step back.  You're misunderstanding how this works.  In make an explicit rule with multiple targets is EXACTLY THE SAME as writing the same rule multiple times, once for each target.  So this:

```
$(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW) : $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)
        @echo copying from $< to $@
        $(call COPY, $(firstword $(TARGET_BIN_LIST)), $@)
```

If `TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW` is `file001.200 file001.201 file001.202 file001.203` and `TARGET_BIN_LIST` is `file001c.200 file001c.201 file001c.202 file001c.203`, is identical to writing this:

```
file001.200 : file001c.200 file001c.201 file001c.202 file001c.203
        ...
file001.201 : file001c.200 file001c.201 file001c.202 file001c.203
        ...
file001.202 : file001c.200 file001c.201 file001c.202 file001c.203
        ...
file001.203 : file001c.200 file001c.201 file001c.202 file001c.203
        ...
```

So you can clearly see that when each rule is run, the value of `$<` and `$(firstword $(TARGET_BIN_LIST))` will be the same thing (`file001c.200`).

Is it really the case that whenever ANY of the `fileXXXc.YYY` files change, you want to rebuild ALL the `fileXXX.YYY` files?  That's what your rule does, but based on the recipe it doesn't seem like that's what you want.

Make is mostly about writing *one rule* to build *one target* from zero or more prerequisites.  If you use a pattern rule you can do this pretty easily:

```
all: $(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW)

file001.% : file001c.%
        @echo copying from $< to $@
        $(call COPY,$<,$@)
```

If your filenames may have a more complex naming convention then you'll need something more complicated.

*ETA:*

Since your naming convention doesn't fit into make's pattern rule capabilities you'll have to do something fancier.  You can use `eval` to generate the rules, like this:

```
all: $(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW)

define TARGET_BIN_COPY
$(1) : $(basename $(1))c$(suffix $(1))
        @echo copying from $$< to $$@
        $$(call COPY,$$<,$$@)
endef

$(foreach T,$(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW),$(eval $(call TARGET_BIN_COPY,$T)))

# uncomment this for debugging
#$(foreach T,$(TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW),$(info $(call TARGET_BIN_COPY,$T)))
```

Comment: The file names are generated based on parameters from the build, so they change, but keep the format AAABCCC.YYY. Because of that, I dont think a pattern will work.

Comment: I don't know what `AAABCCC.YYY` represents.  Is that the target file?  Or the prerequisite file?  What's the naming convention for the other one?

Comment: The naming convention currently consists of a 3 letter name, a 1 letter identifier, a 3 diget number, and the letter 'c'. The file type is a 3 digit number, ie: radK338c.200. The new naming convention is identical, only without the letter 'c'. Not all our tools support the new naming convention, thus we must support both. These names are constructed by the make file given the build parameters so "rad" could be "mom" or "cat" and the 3 digit numbers are a version number that change often. TARGET_BIN_LIST/TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW contain the names with/without the 'c' character respectively.

Comment: Can you explain what the updated code does? I tried it and it didnt work. Also, there is already a rule for 'all', so would that cause a problem?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?  You should remove all other rules for updating these targets.  It's fine to have multiple rules for `all`, as long as only one of them has a recipe.  Explaining exactly how all this works is very complex and will take a long time.  In short, I created a macro `TARGET_BIN_COPY` which contains an entire rule for one target being built from its prerequisite.  Then for each entry in `TARGET_BIN_LIST_NEW` I used `eval` and `call` to create a rule for it.  You can read more about these functions in the GNU make manual.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By didn't work, I mean that it seems that nothing happens. I never see any output generated from this on the console or as output files as if it never executed it.

Comment: I've added a statement to the end that you can uncomment for debugging.  It will  print out the rules that make is evaluating.  See if there's something about those rules that doesn't seem right to you.  Also, you can run `make -d` and examine the output to see why make decides not to rebuild the targets (I assume they're not all up to date!!)  I can't really help more than that; based on the information you've provided that solution should work.  I guess you should also check that you have a reasonably recent version of GNU make; anything older than 3.80 (released in 2002) is too old.

Comment: I get the following error: define TARGET_BIN_COPY
process_begin: CreateProcess((null), define TARGET_BIN_COPY, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make.exe: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: First, you didn't say you were using Windows.  What version of GNU make do you have (`make --version`)?  How was it built (cygwin, mingw, etc.)?  Be sure you're using correct line endings.  That error means either your version of make is too old or you transcoded my example into your makefile incorrectly.  SO comments aren't good for debugging this because there's no formatting, so you'll have to edit your question with the exact makefile (cut and paste please) and exact error message (ditto).

Comment: The line endings were the cause of the problems during execution. I didn't realize that it was so picky! I discovered the filter function and was able to use it to choose the correct file for the copy process. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Again, it would be good if you provided the version of GNU make you're using.  GNU make should support both LF (UNIX) and CRLF (Windows) line endings just fine since 3.78 (1999) although there have been a few bugs over the years.